# Making tree structure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

I want to make a tree structure by `tikz`. I am not a professional latex user and I am just trying to combine examples to make it work but first I would like that the edges have direction and then `T 3` and `T 4` overlap and then I would like to be able to make the space between nodes in each layer being more flexible to change. This in my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=white!20}]]
  \node {P}
    child { node (ch1){char1} 
        child { node {T 1}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 3}
        child { node {comment} } } node [left=2cm of char 1] (s1){script 1}}
    child { node (ch2){char 2} 
      child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 4}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 5}
        child { node {comment} } } node [right=2cm of char 2] (s2){script 2}};
   %Draw edges
   \path [line] (s2) -- node {}(ch2);
   \path [line] (s1) -- node {}(ch1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There is a circle created on the edges between `char 1` and `script 1`. I can not figure why? Any suggestion would be appreciate!!

Comment: Also, there are many packages, which allow you to construct trees which are easier to use.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik If you are referring to `forest`, I agree, but giving a list of packages you have in mind might help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The circles appear because you have `node{}` in `\path [line] (s2) -- node {}(ch2);`
2. You can add arrows by saying `edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex'}`.
3. You were loading `graphdrawing` but it is not obvious to me you were using it.
4. `left=2cm of char 1` should probably be `left=2cm of ch1`.
5. You can change the dimensions/distances at any level using e.g. `level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm},level 3/.style={text width=1cm,font=\tiny}`.
6. To debug you may temporarily set `opacity=0.5` to better understand where some nodes went.
7. The rest of your statements I do not understand. Could you perhaps consider making them clearer?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,%opacity=0.5,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=white!20},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
    edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex'},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm}, 
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
    level 3/.style={text width=1cm,font=\tiny}]
  \node {P}
    child { node (ch1){char1} 
        child { node {T 1}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 3}
        child { node {comment} } } node [left=2cm of ch1] (s1){script 1}}
    child { node (ch2){char 2} 
      child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 4}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 5}
        child { node {comment} } } node [right=2cm of ch2] (s2){script 2}};
   %Draw edges
   \path [line] (s2) -- (ch2);
   \path [line] (s1) -- (ch1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=white!20}]]
  \node {P}
    child { node (ch1){char1} 
        child { node {T 1}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 3}
        child { node {comment} } } node [left=2cm of char 1] (s1){script 1}}
    child { node (ch2){char 2} 
      child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 4}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 5}
        child { node {comment} } } node [right=2cm of char 2] (s2){script 2}};
   %Draw edges
   \path [line] (s2) -- node {}(ch2);
   \path [line] (s1) -- node {}(ch1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am confused by your comments. Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,%opacity=0.5,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=white!20},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
    edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex'},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=30mm}, 
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=15mm},
    level 3/.style={text width=1cm,font=\tiny}]
  \node {P}
    child { node (ch1){char1} 
        child { node {T 1}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 3}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } } node [left=2cm of ch1] (s1){script 1}}
    child { node (ch2){char 2} 
        child { node {T 2}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 4}
        child { node {comment} } }
        child { node {T 5}
        child { node {comment} } } node [right=2cm of ch2] (s2){script 2}};
   %Draw edges
   \path [line] (s2) -- (ch2);
   \path [line] (s1) -- (ch1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this is just to clarify your request, and not a proposal for really do this. (And this is not a tree.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still do not see the leave corresponding to `T 3`. where is it?

Comment: @Dalek It is where you put it: under `T4`. You can check this by adding `opacity=0.5` to the options of `\begin{tikzpicture}`. May I ask where you want to have it?

Comment: but as I said in my question I want to be able to play with the distances of leaves from each other in order to avoid this overlap. How can I include it in my code?

Comment: @Dalek I edited my answer accordingly. (Your question contains a sentence that runs over four lines, I apologize if I missed some things when trying to parse it.)

Comment: @mamot Thanks. Is it possible in the case of shared lower level node, both the higher level `char1` and `char2` be connected to the same node for instance, `T2` instead of having two nodes?

Comment: @Dalek Sorry, again I have trouble interpreting the request. Could you add a sketch to your question that allows others what you have in mind?

Comment: My point is if `T2` is shared between node `char 1` and `char 2`, it can be just placed under one of the higher level leave for instance `char 1` but `char 2` be also connected to it. Instead of current picture that there are two `T2`s.

Comment: @Dalek I added something.....